# Why are DisplayPort KVMs so awful?

Tags: kvm

The DVI KVMs I've been using for years have the property that they make the computer(s) that one is switched away from think that the monitor is still connected. This is, in general, quite useful; in particular, if one attaches a laptop to the KVM with the intent of using the laptop's display alongside the monitor connected to the KVM, windows will not reorient themselves when switching away from the laptop.

From what I can tell from researching DisplayPort KVMs, this property (which I have come to consider one of the main things that a KVM is supposed to do, rather than being a simple switch) seems at least uncommon and perhaps entirely absent from DisplayPort KVMs.

Is there something about DisplayPort as a connectivity standard that has invited this regression? Are there DisplayPort KVMs on the market that will emulate the presence of a monitor?

Comment: Are you asking a general question about KVMs, or are you looking for a replacement that has that feature? If you are looking for a replacement, can you list other requirements that you have for the KVM please?

Comment: I'm not asking about KVMs in general; rather, I'm asking about DisplayPort KVMs in general. I really don't think my original posting was unclear; but I've edited it to add some redundancy.

Comment: Maybe unclear was the wrong close reason, so sorry about that. General questions about hardware are seen as technical support, which is off-topic. Lucky, this question can be saved if you edit your question to ask for a recommendation with the feature(s) you want as the requirements. Please be sure to add as many details to the question as you can.

Comment: Rereading my question again, it does exactly that. What, precisely, is the problem?

Comment: Few more quick questions. How much are you looking to spend and how many monitors/computers do you need supported?

Comment: I'm looking at 4-port single-head units. I'm more concerned with whether the functionality I'm looking for exists in the marketplace than with a price point; but less than $600 would be preferable. I've had a disappointing experience with an Emerson (a.k.a. Avocent a.k.a. Vertiv) SV240D (which certainly does not do what I'm after).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here...  this question is 5 years old.  They exist now, although they can be a bit pricey.

What you seem to be wanting is a displayport kvm with edid emulation.   They are pretty easy to find for hdmi, but are still somewhat unusual for displayport.

[This company](https://connectpro.com/) appears to make displayport kvms that have EDID emulation. I haven't tried them, so I don't know for certain.